# Windows 7 is not picking up microphone voice?

Tags: windows-7

Recently, I ordered one `USB microphone` from amazon for my interview. but its not working . device has installed properly but not audio not recording.
I have been searching for a solution all day but found nothing useful. when I plugged in my PC it's not working.
I tried to test it on https://mictests.com/ on but it's not working

result of the test :

[image]

error that showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0m2n.jpg

Comment: Did you update the Audio driver in your Windows 7 machine?  You need to see if an upgrade is possible and upgrade the driver. Remember that Windows 7 is dead.

Comment: i didn't found proper driver for it then I installed windows 10 but still the same issue

Comment: @SaurabhDhage - I am confused.  Are you running Windows 10 or Windows 7? Does this device work on any computer you have access to?

Comment: @Ramhound I have dual boots. but not working on any of them

Comment: I found solution it was my mistake.In the back side of microphone there is volume control button.i didn't saw it.